# ltrace printf() but shows puts()

Tags: c

Based on my understanding, ltrace utility is used to trace library calls.  I ltrace a simple program which calls `printf` only, but what the library function displayed is `puts` instead of `printf`. I am curious why it does not show `printf` but `puts`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ltrace` shows `puts` being called because it works on the binary file and the binary file calls `puts`.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/iny5K5): source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char *v[])
{
  printf("hello world\n");
}
```

Assembly:

```
.LC0:
        .string "hello world"
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

If you play with more examples, you may find that the compiler produces assembly code that calls `memcpy` when the source code does not, assembly code that does not call `memcpy` (or one of many other common functions) when the source code does, and so on. The compiler only needs to respect the meaning of the program, it does not need to respect the actual functions being called. Since `printf` and `puts` are standard functions that you are not allowed to redefine, it knows what these functions do and can replace one by the other if it deems it useful.

Here, `puts` was substituted to `printf` because `puts` is simpler (it does not interpret `%` formats and it is not variadic), and thus faster. The compiler was allowed to replace `printf` with `puts` in this case because printing the string did not require the interpretation of any format specifier, and the string happened to end in `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I know what is the relationship between printf and puts in here?

Comment: @HuangJie `puts` is simpler (and thus faster) because it does not interpret any `%` format indication. And it adds a `\n` at the end on its own.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an optimization. Compiler replaces `printf("smth\n")` with `puts("smth")` because the output is the same but `puts()` should work faster.